# Converting an object's attribute to an array in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, forms, attributes

I have a form in my Rails application, and in the form, there is a textbox that corresponds to :mylist, which is an attribute of my class Catcher's object @mycatcherobject In the form, people will paste something that looks like this:

FRI.9234.43.32340.pdf

NNY.6042.43.5523.pdf

LJN.9867.56.1659.pdf

After the form is submitted, I need to turn what was pasted into that text box (that is, what is now the value of :mylist) into an array. For the above example, there would be three elements in the array (one for each of the items above).

Do you have any idea how to do this? I can't figure out how to convert an object's attribute's value into an array anywhere.

I've tried things like %w(#{@mycatcherobject.mylist}), but that doesn't work.

I'm fairly new at Rails, so my apologies if this seems obvious. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That comes in the controller as a param[:name of the field] and you can write a regular expression to split the string. In case the elements are separated by a comma or a special character you can do something like

```
result = params[:list].split(",")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I messed around a bit with you suggested. This is what ended up working for me: `mylistarray = @mycatcherobject.mylist.split(",")`

Comment: Sure, done (I'm new, so I'm not clear how things work around here). One thing I'd like to add is that I ended up finally changing my expression to `mylistarray = @mycatcherobject.mylist.split(/[\r\n]+/)`. This pulled out the new line break code and separated the values into three different elements in the array. Before that, with the expression I listed above, they all came together as one long string without breaking apart into three different ones. Once I made this final change, it ended up working perfectly.